# python3: How to get logical complement (negation) of a binary number, eg. '010' => '101'?

Tags: python-3.x, bit-manipulation, complement, negation

Maybe I'm missing something but I can't find a straightforward way to accomplish this simple task. When I go to negate a binary number through the "~" operator it returns a negative number due to the two's complement:

```
>>> bin(~0b100010) # this won't return '0b011101'
'-0b100011'
```

What about if I just want to switch 0s into 1s and vice-versa, like in classic logical complement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> bin(0b111111 ^ 0b100010)
'0b11101'
>>>
```

Comment: Xor-ing with an all 1s mask seems to be the best practice indeed. One must pay attention to the mask length, that must have the same number of digits.

Answer (score 3):

YOU's answer as a function:

```
def complement(n):
    size = len(format(n, 'b'))
    comp = n ^ ((1 << size) - 1)
    return '0b{0:0{1}b}'.format(comp, size)

>>> complement(0b100010)
'0b011101'
```

I made it preserve the bit length of the original. The int constructor doesn't care about the leading zeros:

```
>>> complement(0b1111111100000000)
'0b0000000011111111'

>> int(complement(0b1111111100000000), 2)
255
```

Answer (score 1):

Ultra nasty:

```
>>> '0b' + ''.join('10'[int(x)] for x in format(0b100010,'b')).lstrip('0')
'0b11101'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another couple of functions that returns the complement of a number I came out with.

A one-liner:

```
def complement(c):
    return c ^ int('1'*len(format(c, 'b')), 2)
```

A more mathematical way:

```
def complement(c):
    n=0
    for b in format(c, 'b'): n=n<<1|int(b)^1
    return n
```

---

Moreover, one-linerizing this last one with functools (such baroque):

```
def complement(c):
    return functools.reduce( lambda x,y: x<<1|y, [ int(b)^1 for b in format(c, 'b') ])
```

Finally, a uselessly nerdish variant of the first one that uses math.log to count the binary digits:

```
def complement(c):
    c ^ int('1' * math.floor(math.log((c|1)<<1, 2)), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another function more a 'Hack' for complementing a Integer. You can use the same logic for complementing binary. Wonder why I did not come across python external libs that can do same. The next ver of Python should take care of this in built-ins

> def complement(x):
>
> ```
> b = bin(x)[2:]
> c= []
> for num in b:
>     if num == '1': c.append('0')
>     elif num == '0': c.append('1')
>
> cat = ''.join(c)
> res = int(cat, 2)
> return print(res)
> ```